# Can we consider position space and momentum space of any state $\psi$ as two subspaces (subsystems) and find joint entropy between them?

Tags: entropy, phase-space

For any quantum or classical state e.g coherent state, if we write it in position space and momentum space. Can we consider position space and momentum space of that state as two subspaces (subsystems) and find joint entropy between them?

Comment: No. Position space plus momentum space is not a decomposition of the Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

These are not two different systems but two different representations of the same system. In general, you may be looking for a quasiprobability distribution in order to treat position and momentum on the same footing. Then, you can talk about the entropy of the entire quasiprobability distribution such as through the Wehrl entropy.